# Angular CDK Virtual Scrolling - Text in table is blurry in IE11

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I am using Angular 7 and angular/cdk ver 7.3.7.
I created roughly the same table like the one in this tutorial:
https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/virtual-scrolling-in-angular-7/

While the text in table seems clear in Chome and Edge, it looks blurry in IE11.

Does anyone know why it happens or how to fix it?

Thanks for the help.

Here is the table:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="24" class="cdk-content">
 <table class="list">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>HEADER1</th>
    <th>HEADER2</th>
    <th>HEADER3</th>
    <th>HEADER4</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let rec of record_list;">
    <tr>
      <td>{{rec.item1}}</td>
      <td>{{rec.item2}}</td>
      <td>{{rec.item3}}</td>
      <td>{{rec.item4}}</td>
    </tr>
   </ng-container>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Comment: I've also encountered this issue. Did you discover a fix?

Comment: @Koronag Yes, it seems to be caused by cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport's default css property "transform : translateZ(0px);". The text stopped being blurry by setting transform to none.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding css property like below.

```
.cdk-content{
 ...
 transform : none;
 ...
}
```

cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport's transform value is set to translateZ(0px) by default, which seems to make the text blurry.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
 ...
 transform: none;
 ...
 }
```

place a transform none along with other values. mind that there is no "." in the beginning of cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport